# Line breaks introduced in database export as extra lines in table

Tags: macros, lists, line-breaking, expl3, xparse

I am automating the producing of tex files using an access database with many different types of fields. One, a memo field that will contain an itemized list i.e. visible tex including `\begin{itemize} \item line data \end{itemize}` and this is best kept clean with line breaks. When I type the lines and use the appropriate Ctrl + Enter to force a line break in the access field, all looks good.

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Line 1 
    \item Line 2 
    \item Line 3
\end{itemize}
```

Then I have a script that connects to a query in the database which concatenates a large string of text and memo fields together and saves the complete column into a tex file. Unfortunately this is filled with extra line breaks i.e.

```
\begin{itemize}

    \item Line 1 

    \item Line 2 

    \item Line 3

\end{itemize}
```

All these extra lines are not intended and lead to a `par` ending error in my `XeLaTeX` compile (although I don't think this is an inadequacy on any TeX engine's part).

So to me it looks like this line break is not doing what I thought, but since this special character works behind the scene, I am not quite sure what it is doing and how I can get a single line break in both instances.

I think the cleanest solution would be to using a more appropriate carriage return, in the database producing this tex file, but if there is a TeX reason why these line breaks cause a failure, I would love to know more and would update my question/MWE appropriately.

Note:  This itemized list is actually passed as argument 8 to a new command as defined below (which may be why it is actually more sensitive to whatever newline character is used in the database):

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\WCBlock}{ O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} m O{} }{%
    \begin{ThreePartTable}%
        \begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]%
        \end{TableNotes}%
        \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\raggedleft}
        \begin{longtable}[l]{R{2cm}|L{10.75cm} R{2cm}}%
            \tl_if_blank:nF{#1}{ \multirow{3}{2cm}{#1\\#2\\#6 } & \textbf{#3} & \multirow{2}{2cm}{#5} \\}%
            \tl_if_blank:nF{#4}{ & \emph{#4} &  \\}%
                                 & \multicolumn{2}{L{12cm}}{#7}     \\%
            \tl_if_blank:nF{#8}{ & \multicolumn{2}{L{12cm}}{#8}     \\}%
        \insertTableNotes%
        \end{longtable}%
    \end{ThreePartTable}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: `+O{}` for the last argument.

Comment: @egreg WOW, answer doesn't get much shorter than that.  Indeed that worked.  I am impressed.  And to think, I almost didn't think the `\DeclareDocumentCommand` was relevant to the problem and almost didn't include it.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider using a keyval interface. Eight arguments is well past usable.

Comment: @SeanAllred Are you thinking `pgfkeys` or something?

Comment: Well you're already using expl3 – take a look at l3keys. (And in the off-chance you haven't seen it yet, thumb through `texdoc interface3`.)

Comment: @SeanAllred I have been looking at the `pgfkeys` and `l3keys` and I wanted to check in with you again, because your comment about eight arguments being well past useable has been on my mind. I don't think it's possible for me to use keys, because the contents of the arguments (optional included) are pretty long paragraphs/strings that can include commas which seem to be the general key deliminator. I am automating the production of some tables and layouts, so these commands don't have to be user friendly but still want to use good TeX practise and learn a new technique I have not used before.

Comment: You can protect `,` by making sure it's wrapped in `{…}`: `key = {thing with, commas}, key2 = …`. If you're going to have multiple paragraphs in your keys' values though, perhaps you should take a token-delimited approach (especially since you don't have to deal with maintaining it yourself – you just have to teach TeX what to do with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, arguments passed to a command defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` (which should be preferred to `\DeclareDocumentCommand`) are *short*, that is, they shouldn't contain `\par` (or a blank line, that's the same).

You can make any of the argument *long* by prefixing the argument specifier with `+`: so

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\WCBlock}{ O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} m +O{} }
 {
  ...
 }
```

is what you need. Note that `%` can be omitted for protecting end-of-lines for code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Unrelated, but I'm not sure you should use seven optional arguments: they look mandatory, to me.